# Add Table Column Names from MS SQL in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to add column names from MS SQL using a DNS - Less Connection; I have used the dns-less code to successfully connect but I need the column names to print also.

```
echo "<table>";
while (!$rs->EOF)  //carry on looping through while there are records
{
echo "<tr>";
for ($i=0; $i < $num_columns; $i++) {
echo "<td>" . $fld[$i]->value . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
 $rs->MoveNext(); //move on to the next record
  }

echo "</table>"; //close the connection and recordset objects freeing up resources
```

I know how to modify the table but how do I add the table names?

Comment: there's not enough information here to help you -- can you provide more detail?

Comment: Add code to show MS SQL column labels. Not sure how to use it in this code typical php mysql is very straight forward but does nothing for this type of connection.

Comment: you want to print/echo the column headers? also, you need to show more code (like your connection, querying, etc)

Answer (score 0):

By your code, it's difficult to know how are you filling the variable `$fld`.

I would recommend to see the different ways you can fetch the values for MS SQL [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php).

If you can use `mssql_fetch_assoc` the the key of the array is the field (column) name.